# gganimate map not loading

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm animating county-level for the US over time. I can make the ggplot easily enough (so I know my data's in the right condition for shape files), but every time I include transition_time() or transition_state() to animate it, the "map" I get is either fully empty or fully empty after the first frame. Specifically, *this* works:

```
# Plot graph of January sales prices--works just fine ...
playdata_one = subset(playdata, playdata$date == 202001)
graph1 = ggplot() + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  labs(title = "Median sales prices", subtitle = "January 2020") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +  
  geom_polygon(data = playdata_one, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = saleprice, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(data = states, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color="black", fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_viridis(na.value="transparent")
```

But this doesn't:

```
# Plot animated graph of January to March--fails ...
graph2 = ggplot() + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  labs(title = "Median sales prices", subtitle = "{unique(msa_map_final$date[msa_map_final$date == {frame_time}])}") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +  
  geom_polygon(data = playdata, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = saleprice, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(data = states, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color="black", fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_viridis(na.value="transparent") + 
  transition_states(date)

anim = animate(graph2)
anim
```

Any thoughts? I've uploaded my full (example) code & data [here](https://github.com/burialrune/home-playdata).

Comment: Where does playdata come from? Can you please make this question reproducible, so that we can run the code and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi, Jon! I think the playdata + playcode on GitHub should be enough to reproduce the error and, hopefully, reveal its cause to one smarter than I. The data's from https://www.zillow.com/research/data/ --"Median Sale Price (Smooth, All Homes, Monthly View)"; before playdata, I just merged that with an MSA/county crosswalk, then limited the data to two states & three months in 2020 (for size).

Comment: I think the problem is from `subtitle`. Remove subtitle, your code works on my side.

Comment: Zhiqiang--interesting. Removing the subtitle definitely helps, but on my end it's now missing all the California MSAs (apparently just showing the one Arizona MSA instead). Are you seeing similarly?

Comment: I have deleted my previous answer and added a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only see Arizona because your data are predominantly from Arizona. I only selected a subset of `playdata` as `df` to show this. The problem of your original code is `subtitle` which needs to be consistent with `transition_states`.

```
df <- playdata %>% filter(date >=201912, date <202005)

graph2 = ggplot() + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  labs(title = "Median sales prices", 
       subtitle = "{unique(df$date[df$date == {closest_state}])}"
       ) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +  
  geom_polygon(data = states, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color="black", fill = NA) +
  geom_polygon(data = df, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = saleprice, group = group)) + 
    scale_fill_viridis(na.value="transparent") + 
  transition_states(date)
  
frames<-  df$date %>% unique %>% length
anim = animate(graph2, nframes=frames)

anim
```

[image]